# I want to display Products.MenuName in menuData.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, frontend

I want to display Products.MenuName in menuData.json but it doesn't work. How can I call Products data? Here are my json data and function.

```
     "d": {
       "PageCount": 4,
       "RowCount": 12,
       "ResultSet": [
          {
           "Menu": "Hamburger Menu",
           "Price": -1,
           "Products": [
                {         
                 "MenuName": "Chips ",
                 "ExtendedPrice": "7,00",         
                }
            ]
          }
        }


     $.getJSON('menuData.json', function(read_data){
        $.each(read_data.d.ResultSet.Products,function(i,food){      
           $("#hims").append("Menus: "+food.MenuName);
         });
        });
     <button id="getdata-button">Click Me</button>
     <div id="hims"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to product in this way, you have to iterate over `ResultSet` first.

```
$.getJSON('menuData.json', function(read_data){
  $.each(read_data.d.ResultSet,function(i,result){  
    $.each(result.Products,function(i,food){      
      $("#hims").append("Menus: "+food.MenuName);
    });
  });
});
```